# pass & character in a GET

Tags: html, get

How can i pass a & character in a get like this:

script.php?file_name=A&O.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to url-encode the char (as %26), see http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

There are functions to do that in many programming langs, such as [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) in PHP.